What is opinion?
It is commonly agreed that there is a clear distinction between fact and opinion. Physical facts can be verified. Opinion varies and may be based on faith. But what about opinions which, over time, become accepted as facts within society? For example, the idea of social equality was once an opinion, but this view is now accepted as fact - the background of society. Social equality is simply one example of this phenomenon. It is a social fact.

I think you are confusing the moral opinion that everybody should have equal rights in a society - an idea that has indeed been spreading and is now largely accepted - and actual equality which, unfortunately, is still not a fact. So one way to answer your question is to bring up the distinction between moral statements, who are always opinions, and factual statements, who can be opinions when they are not justified. See moral skepticism.

Social equality is not an accepted fact as multiple studies of social inequality would attest. What might be accepted, and far from universally, is that social equality is desirable, but that is a social value and values generally can be neither true nor false, let alone be facts. Some share a value, others do not, but however many do share it there is no "verifying" what should be the case, only what the case is.

Please see edit to clarify this point. Social equality is a fact in law. The law regulates what is acceptable, not what exists. Similarly, "Slavery is unacceptable" is a fact in law. However, it was once just an opinion.

The law is a normative prescription, but that is not a fact. There is a discrepancy between ideal prescriptions and factual practice. It is a fact there is a law to bring about greater equity, but it is not a fact that said equity exists. The main question, however is quite a valid philosophical concern.

@JD A 'fact of law' is absolutely a thing.  And what the law is, is also a fact.

" For example, the idea of social equality was once an opinion, but this view is now accepted as fact." The idea that social equality is a good thing is an opinion and it's not universally held. That the law requires equality (or attempts to) in some places and contexts is a fact. There's no contradiction between these.

@JimmyJames There are facts of law, but prescriptions of law are not facts; consider IN's attempt to legislate the value of Pi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_pi_bill It was a fact of IN law that Pi was exactly 3, but such a "fact" is a prescription that is not a fact. Pi has never been, is not, and never will be exactly 3 according to mathematicians.

@JD It's a fact that such a law existed, though.

@JimmyJames Hmmm. I guess those would be 'facts about law' as opposed to be 'facts of law', eh? How epistemologically fine-haired.

@JD I'm not trying to be pedantic (at least not on purpose.) I think the question is fundamentally about language and that the word 'fact' has two closely related but distinct meanings. Misunderstanding is almost inevitable. It also occurs to me that it is much easier to define opinions than facts.

There are facts in law. Paradoxically, a good example is the legal fiction. If a married woman gives birth within a year of her husband's death, the child is presumed to be her husband's. This may or not be a biological fact but it is a fact in common law. Similarly, equal treatment under the law is now a fact. In earlier times, slavery was a fact.

An opinion is simply another term for belief.

Some opinions may also be fact. E.g. my opinion that the Earth is not flat.

Some opinions are not fact. E.g. a flat-Earther's opinion that the Earth is flat.

For some opinions, it is unknown whether they are fact. E.g. an opinion that extra-terrestrials exist.

Some opinions are simply value or aesthetic judgments not capable of being proved true or false.



Some additional nuance can be added by dividing opinions into those that are factual claims and those that are not.
Opinions in categories 1 through 3 are factual claims. Opinions in category 4 are not a factual claims.
The relationship looks like this:
opinions ⊃ factual claims ⊃ facts

+1 This is concise and accurate. To supplement, opinions necessarily lend themselves to Disagreement (SEP).

I disagree with your third line about flat-earthers.  Facts can be true or false (or undetermined) but a fact being false doesn't make it an opinion.

@Lowri Right, so I don't think flat-earthers are saying that their opinion is that the world is flat (well some might because they aren't using the right word.)  Flat-earthers are making a factual claim that the earth is actually flat, in objective reality.

@DikranMarsupial Flat earther's don't have an 'opinion' that the earth is flat. I've wasted more than enough time arguing with some of them to know that.  An opinion would be something like "a flat earth is a more elegant theory."

I don't think this is quite right. As used in common language, opinion implies something like normative acknowledged fallibility - a kind of belief that a person under that person's circumstances would normally acknowledge could be incorrect or subjective.

@JimmyJames "It ain't what you don't know that gets you into trouble. It's what you know for sure that just ain't so." - Mark Twain


It is commonly agreed that there is a clear distinction between fact and opinion. Physical facts can be verified. Opinion varies and may be based on faith. But what about opinions which, over time, become accepted as facts within society?

Physical fact can be verified independently from the observer. That is, whoever performs an experiment would arrive at the same result, regardless of their prior belief on the matter (given that they have sufficient skills to actually conduct the experiment.)
Opinion accepted in society does not satisfy this condition - they are accepted because everyone is conditioned (by the society, education, etc.) to think in certain way. But if the facts are contrary to the opinion - checking them would still produce the same result.
(Fictional) 5 monkeys experiment is a well-known example of an accepted opinion (usually framed as a "corporate culture") - no one climbs the ladder, even though the cold shower might be turned off by now, and any experiment would confirm it.
image source


For example, the idea of social equality was once an opinion, but this view is now accepted as fact - the background of society. Social equality is simply one example of this phenomenon.

If social equality has become accepted by the (mostly western) society, it is because all the groups that were emancipated (women, non-whites, Jews, homosexuals) proved themselves equal to the white straight Christian men. In this sense, what is accepted is not the prevalent opinion, but the fact that people are indeed equal, provided equal circumstances and opportunities.
Another example is Ruth Bader Ginsburg popular, but actually silly remark about 9 women in the supreme court:

“When I’m sometimes asked ‘When will there be enough [women on the Supreme Court]?’ and I say ‘When there are nine,’ people are shocked. But there’d been nine men, and nobody’s ever raised a question about that.” -RBG

Given about equal ratio of men and women in the US, the probability of 9 members of the same sex is about one in 500 - extremely unlikely. Thus, a statistician would say that the all-male supreme court was indicative of a discrimination of females. Likewise, an all-female supreme court, contrary to a widespread opinion, would not signify equality - rather it would indicate that women reversed the tables, and men became in fact the discriminated sex.

I suppose we should verbalize our reasons, to inform others about them, rather than just beating people. Then even if we continued to do the same thing, at least everyone would know why.

@ScottRowe reasoning makes for a weaker arguing position - since you might be wrong, or you the opponent might be a better debater. Reasoning also requires accepting the idea that you might be wrong. It requires looking both sides of the issue - who could dare to speak against equality?

Or you might be wrong. (It bears repeating.) If one cannot accept the idea of being wrong, then there is no point in using words at all. One approach is to stop using irrelevant criteria, like sex, age, race, sexual orientation, culture... We would have to accept that 99% of what we 'know' is just random gibberish uttered by the idiot evolution. Ugh. Sad but true. If one recoils from that, it's hard to have a conversation.

Note that the monkey experiment is a urban legend and was never put in practice

@armand I don't think anyone treats this story as a real experiment - rather it illustrates the behavior that is all to familiar in human society - at work, in SE communities, in politics. Though in western politics it often takes form of political polarization - when one is boxed into sticking to one of two counterfactual views.

You just did. And honestly, every time I see it presented, it's never like a fable or cautionary tale, but always as an "experiment" as they can be done by lab coat scientists. Probably because it's more convincing with the appearance of reality and science. But if you know it's not a real experiment it's quite strange, to not say manipulative, to present it as such.

@armand I have never claimed that it was a real experiment or relied on its results: it merely illustrates here the difference between an opinion/belief (shower is on) and a fact (shower may be off.) Just in case I added word "fictional" in the text - which IMHO does not affect in any way the point being made, contrary to your statement above.

I detect naughty bad faith... When you talk of an "experiment" without mentioning it's fictional people are naturally going to assume it's a real one. You did well to edit your answer.

@armand I have never understood what french mean by "bad faith" (mauvaise foi) - to me it sounds as an accusation of lying, which in my culture is considered an insult. What annoyed me about your comments us the fallacious argument, which focused on a matter tangential to what was actually duscussed.

This is about the notion of fact in science. In law, the term fact is used differently.

@reinierpost write an answer - what's the point of telling this in a comment?

@reinierpost regarding why scientific criteria are not even considered in legal practice: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/116750/61899

I would caution against answers which postulate a dichotomy between Fact and Opinion. Consider the fact,
F= Speed of light is 3x10^8 m/s
It is not as if this proposition was hooked on to every photon which we then observe like prices in a super market.
Instead we construct elaborate theories which gives us good reason to hold F. All empirical theories are under determined. And therefore is the fact F. Theory construction necessarily relies on what are epistemic values (close enough to aesthetic judgements like simplicity, parsimony, symmetry and etc.)
Consider the following propositions:

Hitler was a bad man.
My sons teacher hits her students. She is cruel.

Are cruel and bad descriptions or evaluations (opinions)?
I will recommend reading: Hilary Putnam The collapse of the fact value dichotomy and other essays

A clear distinction can be made, if one accepts one's sensory organs to be trustable.  Perhaps the combination of them allows us to "know as a fact" that we see a car go by us.  We have two eyes to check this agreement -- that's pretty good.  We can add the fact that sound was correlated, but this happens in movie theatres as well.  So perhaps vision and touch are always enough to settle a "FACT".

That’s not the point, I assume that my sensory organs like eyes and ears are “veridical”.  But one does not see/hear propositions in nature. Propositions are about Nature. They must be humanly constructed. It is propositions of which we say, whether they are fact or opinion. There are two options: either conclude that seeing or hearing is conceptual (an option I find unsatisfying as a naturalist) or admit a break between conceptual and nonceptualism.

I think one of the things that trip people up around this is the common notion that facts are true statements.  A fact can be false and it's necessarily the case that most facts are actually false.  I find it interesting to read old scientific literature and see all the incorrect facts that were accepted at the time of writing.  The Half-life of Facts is a book about how that process works.
The difference between a fact and an opinion is intention.  A fact (or factual claim) is an assertion of belief in something that can be objectively determined.  That is, for something to be a fact, it must be a claim that can be evaluated as true or false.  An opinion is something that is subjective.

Fact
2: a piece of information presented as having objective reality

For example, if someone says: "Van Gough is the best painter of all time," that's an opinion.  There's no objective measure of painting that would allow for that to be evaluated as a fact.  If someone says, however, "I think Van Gough is the best painter of all time" that's a statement of fact (about their personal opinion) even if they are lying and really think Bob Ross is better.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

An opinion is a personal judgement. Something is deemed as either good or bad.
An opinion has no truth value. Beliefs or facts are not opinions.

moral judgment... maybe you mean value judgment?? The usual dichotomy is fact vs value

This would be a pretty good answer but 'moral' seems to be the wrong word.  I don't like the taste of raw cucumbers. I think they taste better pickled. That's definitely an opinion but I don't think it's immoral to like cucumbers.

I like that you separated "belief" from "opinion".  Most people conflate these, but a belief is an opinion/theory that one has accepted as a fact.  This is where things go awry.

In our present state of malaise -- probably the worst than any time in history, one can hardly separate fact from opinions because of the use of heresy.  That is, people use the power of the authoritative voice to state an opinion or theory (like in science media or the church) as a fact -- without qualifying the statement with words like "Jesus is GOD [I believe].".
This is a type of sin and false witness, yet science and religion are doing it all of the time.  What are kids supposed to trust when everyone wants to sound like they're an expert with an authoritative tone like the people on TV (which they don't believe)?  This is a serious social disease.
You can note that my last sentence is a logical predicate.  You can see it as a fact or an opinion (including this one), but there are logical and demonstrable reasons to accept it as fact.
